# Where is the database file created in this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code embedded in a .html.erb file:

```
require 'sqlite3'

# Open a SQLite 3 database file
db = SQLite3::Database.new 'file.db'

# Create a table
result = db.execute <<-SQL
  CREATE TABLE numbers (
    name VARCHAR(30),
    val INT
  );
SQL

# Insert some data into it
{ 'one' => 1, 'two' => 2 }.each do |pair|
  db.execute 'insert into numbers values (?, ?)', pair
end

# Find some records
db.execute 'SELECT * FROM numbers' do |row|
  p row
end
```

As you can see the code is creating a database, then create a table, etc..
**My problem**: I don't know where the file "file.db" is created. I have searched for it on the whole Windows, but I cannot find it.

**NOTE 1:** it seems the file and the table are being created, because if I request for the same .html.erb, I get `Error: the table 'numbers' already exists.`

**NOTE 2:** I know this is not the best place to add the ruby code related to a database. I know I should write it on the controller.

Here it is the full code:

```
<%

require 'sqlite3'

# Open a SQLite 3 database file
db = SQLite3::Database.new 'development.sqlite3'

# Create a table
result = db.execute <<-SQL
  CREATE TABLE numbers (
    name VARCHAR(30),
    val INT
  );
SQL

# Insert some data into it
{ 'one' => 1, 'two' => 2 }.each do |pair|
  db.execute 'insert into numbers values (?, ?)', pair
end

# Find some records
db.execute 'SELECT * FROM numbers' do |row|
  p row
end

%>

<h1>Welcome#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/welcome/index.html.erb</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for file.db. SQL lite is a truly light database. To view the tables and records read following:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_create_database.htm

Comment: Thanks, the file was in the project root directory

Comment: I would recommend reading about SQL lite. Because, if you take some time to understand how it works, you would find it much easier to work with it.

Comment: Please include the relevant info here, rather than just linking to it.